# Compare two time in javascript in format 'hh:mm tt'

Tags: javascript, date, time

I want to compare two times
So I tried these:

```
"01:03 AM" > "01:02 AM"
> true
```

```
"01:01 AM" > "01:02 AM"
> false
```

In these cases the results were correct, but not in this one:

```
"12:55 AM" > "03:55 AM"
> true
```

How can I compare two times in this format `"hh:mm tt"` with proper accuracy?
Is it necessary to include the dates with the times, and then compare the dates and times?

Comment: You are doing a string comparison and `1 > 0` so!

Comment: You can't compare a string as time, you should convert the time in timestamps and then compare those

Comment: if you want to manage the date using javascript so i recomend for you this javascript library. http://momentjs.com/docs/ it"s is very powerful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Since space separated date is not supported by safari, using slash instead of space works across all browsers.

You'll need to convert the time into Date Object first and then into timestamp. Then you can compare the timestamp. You can follow this basic example:

```
var t = new Date();
d = t.getDate();
m = t.getMonth() + 1;
y = t.getFullYear();

//Convert time into date object
var d1 = new Date(m + "/" + d + "/" + y + " " + "12:55 AM");
var d2 = new Date(m + "/" + d + "/" + y + " " + "03:55 AM");

//Get timestamp
var t1 = d1.getTime();
var t2 = d2.getTime();
t1 > t2 ? alert("t1 greater than t2") : alert("t2 greater than t1");
```

But for the complicated time comparison, you should use a plugin.

Comment: @Alex I didn't got any errors. You can try this demo in safari:http://jsfiddle.net/ph2oo7a6/

Comment: I edited your fiddle,.. demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ph2oo7a6/1/ ,.. open this link in safari

Comment: @Alex Got the issue: Updated the answer. Demo here :http://jsfiddle.net/ph2oo7a6/3/

Answer (score 1):

Convert the time to minutes and compare

```js
function toMin(str) {
  var match = str.match(/(\d+):(\d+)\s(AM|PM)/)
  var min = (+match[1] > 11 ? 0 : match[1] * 60) + +match[2];
  if (match[3].toLowerCase() == 'pm') {
    min += 720;
  }
  return min;
}

function gt(v1, v2) {
  snippet.log(v1 + ' > ' + v2 + ': ' + (toMin(v1) > toMin(v2)))
}

function lt(v1, v2) {
  snippet.log(v1 + ' < ' + v2 + ': ' + (toMin(v1) < toMin(v2)))
}

//then

gt('12:30 AM', '01:00 AM');
lt('12:30 AM', '01:00 AM');
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Alex it is valid isn't it... what is the expected o/p

Comment: 12:00 AM > 10:36 AM: false, but 12 is greater than 10?

Comment: @Alex no 12:00 AM is midnight 12